# Changing CSS class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the CSS class of a couple DIVs, Linked below is my jFiddle

The only change is that the -selected class actually has a background image which seems to have the background color of the -non-selected class.

The other problem is after selecting another div, you can't select the first one again. What exactly is jQuery doing with the classes? When I add the -non-selected class to it, it should become select-able again, right?

http://jsfiddle.net/9FZcz/

jQuery

```
$(".selector-box").click(function () {
    $(".selector-box-selected").removeClass("selector-box-selected").addClass("selector-box");
    $(this).removeClass("selector-box").addClass("selector-box-selected");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="selector-box-selected"></div>
<div class="selector-box"></div>
<div class="selector-box"></div>
<div class="selector-box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.selector-box{
    margin-bottom:2px;
    width:328px;
    height:46px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.selector-box-selected{
    margin-bottom:2px;
    width:351px;
    height:46px;
    background-image:url(../images/layout/SelectedArrow.png);
}
```

Comment: I try your code
`<div class="selector-box"></div>
<div class="selector-box"></div>
<div class="selector-box"></div>
<div class="selector-box"></div>`
Like this it's work

Answer (score 5):

You should try another way to adding and removing classes, try this one :

```
$(".selector-box").click(function () {
    $('.selector-box').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danzkusuma/9FZcz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I change your code abit

```
<div name="ss" class="selector-box-selected"></div>
<div name="ss" class="selector-box"></div>
<div name="ss" class="selector-box"></div>
<div name="ss" class="selector-box"></div>

$("div[name=ss]").click(function () {
    $("div[name=ss]").removeClass("selector-box-selected").addClass("selector-box");
    $(this).removeClass("selector-box").addClass("selector-box-selected");
});
```

don't mind a name SS, change it to what you want :D

Comment: Thank you Vinh, that answers my first question

Comment: I base on your code but danzkusuma's answer is better, use his code. I recommend
`$(".selector-box").click(function () {
    $('.selector-box').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});`

Comment: As for my second question, in my actual code, selector-box has a background color while selector-box-selected is a background image.

When I click on a 'selector-box' to change it to 'selector-box-selected' it changes the width & height however does not get rid of the background color it seems. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Vinh - your solution would work except both divs have an opacity of .25 so you can see the other one underneath

Comment: In chrome I tested, I use your code and make it's opacity is .25 but it's keep working. div with `selector-box-selected` change width and height and it doesn't laid on other div at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with not being able to select the first one again is that the click event is not being linked to it, since you only apply it to the `<div>` elements with the class `.selector-box`. Apart from that, CSS seems fine, check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9FZcz/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers posted that suggests solutions that requires some refactoring, like adding a `selected` class to selected elements rather than having seperate `selector-box-selected` and `selector-box` classes.

While I think **you should perform the refactoring** since it makes the overall design better and leads to less CSS code duplication, here's a solution without refactoring the code.

I kept track of the last selected element to avoid looping over all of boxes to remove the selected class.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9FZcz/7/)

```
var selectedBox = $('.selector-box-selected').get();

$('.selector-box').add(selectedBox).click(function () {

    if (selectedBox === this) return;

    selectedBox = $([this, selectedBox])
        .toggleClass('selector-box-selected')
        .toggleClass('selector-box')
        .get(0);
});
```